# Self refence within class methods in Itcl

Tags: tcl, itcl

Is it possible to refer to current object within the member method of a class.
Kindly consider the code below:

```
itcl::class widget {
   private variable inst

   method ChildCount {} {
       return [llength [keylkeys inst children]]
   }
   method AddChild {childWidget} {
       inst children.[ChildCount] $childWidget
       # ***HOW TO GET THIS WORKING?***
       $childWidget SetParent $self
   }
}
```

What could be the equivalent for `$self` in `$childWidget SetParent $self`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so evident after little more online search -> `$this` variable should do the the trick.

Comment: This is the answer: itcl provides the reference to the current object in the variable named `this`, visible inside the body of methods.